# triviality of etale fundamental group vs triviality of topological fundamental group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, arithmetic-geometry

Let $k$ be a number field with a fixed embedding to $ \mathbb{C}$. If $V$ is an algebraic variety over $k$ and $V_\mathbb{C} = V \times_k \mathbb{C}$ has nice enough properties one can show that the profinite completion of the topological fundamental group $\pi_1(V(\mathbb{C}))$ is the etale fundamental group $\pi^{et}_1(V_\mathbb{C})$. I'm omitting basepoints for simplicity. My question is:

> Is there an example of a smooth projective geometrically connected algebraic variety $V$ over $k$ such that $\pi_1(V(\mathbb{C})) \neq 0$ and $\pi^{et}_1(V_\mathbb{C}) = 0$?

I suspect the answer is yes based on the example of the unit circle, which has $\mathbb{Z}$ as topological fundamental group and has trivial profinite completion.

Comment: See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/126489/is-there-non-simple-connected-projective-varietyover-c-with-trivial-etale-fund)

Comment: @Rieux thanks, I wasn't expecting it to be an open problem! Do you know by any chance if the answer to my question is known if we drop the smoothness condition? In the link above, the answer is yes if $k= \mathbb{C}$ and they construct an algebraic variety directly over $\mathbb{C}$, but I wonder what happens if I require my variety over $\mathbb{C}$ to come from basechange of a variety over a number field $k$...